# JPASpringDataRepository partial save

Tags: database, spring-boot, spring-data

I am creating a web application with Spring Boot which uses Spring Data JPA for the database access. I have created a Repository class that extends the JpaRepository as follows:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository <MyClass, Integer>{

}
```

I am invoking this method from my controller as follows:

```
myRepo.save(myclassList); //myclassList is a List<MyClass>
```

In the database table corresponding to myclass, there is a unique constraint on one of the columns. So if the constraint is violated, an exception is thrown. However ideally, I would want the save method to work for those records that do not violate the constraint. However sadly this is not the case. So if the unique constraint is violated for even one record, none of the records get inserted into the database. Is there any workaround for this? Or will I need to manually check each record to see if it exists in the DB and only insert the ones that do not exist in the database?

Comment: can you show your `MyClass` entity

Answer (score 0):

> will I need to manually check each record to see if it exists in the DB and only insert the ones that do not exist in the database?

**Short answer**

Yes.

**Longer Version**

The exact way to proceed depends on your specific use case. I see the following options:

1. Make sure your data is valid before you save it. This is probably the default approach
2. Save each entity in a separate transaction, this way the rollback will only rollback the changes to that one entity.
3. Try to save everything in one transaction. If it fails fallback to 1. or 2. This is a little more coding but probably has the best performance if constraint violations are a rare event.

Comment: Thanks, So I will modify my code to manually check each record before inserting into the database.